# PHP preg_split Input by <br>, <br/>, <p> into Separate Paragraphs

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-match, preg-match-all, preg-split

I am curling from a page with very ill-formed code. There is a particular snippet of the page I am trying to parse into paragraphs. This input snippet may be divided by `<p>` and `</p>` or separated by one or more `<br>` or `<br/>` tags. In cases where there are two `<br>` tags after another, I don't want those to be two separate pargaraphs.

My current code I'm trying to parse/display with is

```
$paragraphs = preg_split('/(<\s*p\s*\/?>)|(<\s*br\s*\/?>)|(\s\s+)|(<\s*\/p\s*\/?>)/', $article, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
$paragraphcount = count($paragraphs);
for($x = 1; $x <= $paragraphcount; $x++ )
    {
    echo "<p>".$paragraphs[$x-1]."</p>";
    }
```

However, this is not working as expected. Some different inputs/outputs are as follows:

Input 1: `first part </p> <p> second part </p> <p> third part </p> <p> fourth part <br/>`

Output 1: `<p>first part </p><p> </p><p>second part </p><p> </p><p> third part </p><p> </p><p>fourth part</p><p>  </p>`

My code *is* parsing the input into paragraphs; however, it's also adding extra paragraphs containing only a *space*.

Any help would be appreciated.

Input is UTF-8 if it makes a difference.

Comment: How are you imploding the split values? You are probably imploding on the empty values as well; https://eval.in/498789.

Comment: @chris85, sorry, I forgot to mention that my input sometimes looks like: `first part <br/><p> </p> <p> second part </p><p> </p> <p> third part </p> <p> fourth part <br/>`

Comment: This is resolved now it looks like? Also `$paragraphcount = count($paragraphs);
for($x = 1; $x <= $paragraphcount; $x++ )` can be removed and use `foreach($paragraphs as $paragraph)` then use `$paragraph` in the iteration.

Comment: Thanks @chris85. The reason I have `$paragraphcount` is because I am displaying the paragraphs in different ways (but not here in this code to keep things simpler), depending on how many paragraphs there are (there aren't always the same number of paragraphs). Yes, it is resolved--unless there is a way to do everything using just one regex unlike the way I twisted @zahur-sh's answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution with `preg_replace`:

```
$article = "first part </p> <p> second part </p> <p> third part </p> 
            <p> fourth part <br/> <br> fifth part";
$healed = substr(
          preg_replace('/(\s*<(\/?p|br)\s*\/?>\s*)+/u', "</p><p>", "<p>$article<p>"),
          4, -3);
```

It first wraps the string in `<p>` and then replaces (repetitions of) the variants of breaks by `</p><p>`, to finally remove the starting `</p>` and ending `<p>`. Note that this does not produce an (intermediate) array, but the final string.

```
echo $healed;
```

outputs:

```
<p>first part</p><p>second part</p><p>third part</p><p>fourth part</p><p>fifth part</p>
```

Note that you need the `u` [modifier](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) at the end of the regular expression to get UTF-8 support.

If on the other hand you need the paragraphs in an array, then [`preg_split`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) is better suited (using the same regular expression):

```
$paragraphs = preg_split('/(\s*<(\/?p|br)\s*\/?>\s*)+/u',
                         $article, null, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

If you then write:

```
foreach ($paragraphs as $paragraph) {
    echo "$paragraph\n";
}
```

You get:

```
first part
second part
third part
fourth part
fifth part
```

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to mention that my input sometimes looks like: `first part <br/><p> </p> <p> second part </p><p> </p> <p> third part </p> <p> fourth part <br/>`

Also, I want to display it using an array.

Comment: This input has p tags containing only one space or two spaces between the p tags which renders these as "parts" of the array. `<p> </p>` or `<p>  </p>`

Comment: This code `$paragraphs = substr(preg_replace('/(\s*<(\/?p|br)\s*\/?>\s*)+/', "</p><p>", "<p>$article<p>"), 4, -3);` outputs -> `<p> first part</p><p>�</p><p>second part</p><p>�</p><p>third part</p><p>�</p><p>fourth part` and this code `$paragraphs = mb_substr(mb_ereg_replace('/(\s*<(\/?p|br)\s*\/?>\s*)+/', "</p><p>", "<p>$article<p>"), 4, -3);` outputs -> `<p><p> first part</p> <p> </p> <p>second part</p> <p> </p> <p>third part</p> <p> </p> <p>fourth part` Maybe it's a UTF-8 problem? Strangely, it works on https://eval.in/499354 but not with my UTF-8 input which outputs as I've described above

Comment: Ah, yes, try with the `u` modifier at the end of the regular expression. PHP is strange when it comes to dealing with unicode. Yet we live in 2016... amazing it still does such things.

Comment: Thanks, that did it! But how can I make `$healed` an array instead of a string? I've tried various inefficient combinations of `explode` and `preg_replace`, but can't quite get it to work.

Comment: I added to my answer the way to get the array instead of the "healed" HTML. Thank you for having accepted. Let me know if this is what you need.

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly. If you have any tips/references as to how/where I can learn more about regex, that would be amazing.

Comment: This site: http://www.rexegg.com. Has also specifics on PHP regex features. Use the side menu to make your pick.

Answer (score 2):

```
print_r(preg_split('/((<\s*p\s*\/?>\s*)|(<\s*br\s*\/?>\s*)|(\s\s+)|(<\s*\/p\s*\/?>\s*))+/', $article, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY));
```

result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => first part 
    [1] => second part 
    [2] => third part 
    [3] => fourth part 
)
```

Comment: I used a twisted version of yours:

`$paragraphs = preg_split('/((<\s*p\s*\/?>\s*)|(<\s*br\s*\/?>\s*)|(\s\s+)|(<\s*\/p\s*\/?>\s*))+/', $article, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

foreach ($paragraphs as $key=>&$value) {
 if (strlen($value) < 12) {
  unset($paragraphs[$key]);
 }
}

$paragraphs = array_values($paragraphs);
$paragraphcount = count($paragraphs);
for($x = 1; $x <= $paragraphcount; $x++ )
 {
 echo "<p>".$paragraphs[$x-1]."</p>";
 }`

I forgot to mention that my input sometimes looks like: `first part <br/><p> </p> <p> second part </p><p> </p> <p> third part </p> <p> fourth part <br/>`